# Display External Webpage in Custom Record Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, embedded

I need to add an external webpage to a record page of a custom object. I have reviewed information here: [Display External Webpage in Lead](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/218400/display-external-webpage-in-lead). I am testing in my developer ORG and it is pulling in the data from the website. However, the image is extremely small. Is there a way to change the apex to adjust the size of the image? (I am not a developer) I am using the APEX from the linked page above for the VF (replacing the URL with my own):

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

@Debbie Hoogstraat Yes you can control the image size by applying a overall image size in your Visualforce page like below:

`img { height: 10px; }`

But if there is a particular image you wanted to increase the size and leave the other images on the page untouched, then grab the image class name by inspecting the img element (a.k.a Chrome developer tools ==> Console window)

[image]

If you found the class, then you can apply css style like below:

`img.class_name { height: 10px; }`

Let me know if the above solution helps!